# Python Pandas: select column with the number of unique values greater than 10

Tags: python, pandas

In R, we can use `sapply` to extract columns with the number of unique values greater than 10 by:

```
X[,  sapply(X,  function(x) length(unique(x)))  >=10]
```

How can we do the same thing in Python Pandas?

Also, how can we choose columns with missing proportion less than 10% like what we can do in R:

```
X[,  sapply(X,  function(x) sum(is.na(x))/length(x)  )  < 0.1]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.nunique.html) with `apply`, because it works only with `Series`:

```
print (df.ix[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()) >= 10])
```

and second [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html):

```
print (df.ix[:, df.isnull().mean() <  0.1])
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,np.nan,3],
                   'B':[4,4,np.nan],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[3,3,5]})

print (df)
     A    B  C  D
0  1.0  4.0  7  3
1  NaN  4.0  8  3
2  3.0  NaN  9  5
```

```
print (df.ix[:, df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique()) >= 2])
     A  C  D
0  1.0  7  3
1  NaN  8  3
2  3.0  9  5

print (df.isnull().sum())
A    1
B    1
C    0
D    0
dtype: int64

print (df.isnull().sum() / len(df.index))

A    0.333333
B    0.333333
C    0.000000
D    0.000000
dtype: float64

print (df.isnull().mean())
A    0.333333
B    0.333333
C    0.000000
D    0.000000
dtype: float64


print (df.ix[:, df.isnull().sum() / len(df.index) <  0.1])
   C  D
0  7  3
1  8  3
2  9  5
```

Or:

```
print (df.ix[:, df.isnull().mean() <  0.1])
   C  D
0  7  3
1  8  3
2  9  5
```